# Sort an array of object by timestamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following object :

```
var jsonList = {
   ref : "TEST1",
   inventory : [
         {
            id : "a1",
            date : 1401462270
         },
         {
            id : "a2",
            date : 1414836094
         }
   ]
}
```

inventory array is not sorted by date, i would like to sort this array of object by date. The more recent in first position.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Show what have you tried first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are integers, you can return the difference for comparing.

```js
var jsonList = { ref: "TEST1", inventory: [{ id: "a1", date: 1401462270 }, { id: "a2", date: 1414836094 }] },
    sorted = jsonList.inventory.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.date - b.date;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sorted, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: It wouldn't matter if they were strings (e.g. `date : "1414836094"`), the `-` operator coerces the values to Number. The example would be better if the dates weren't sorted to start with. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorted = jsonList.inventory.sort(function(a,b) {
   return a.date < b.date ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: What about if `a == b`? Maybe `return a.date - b.date`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.